# Textractor Queries CLI syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-textract

I am trying to use the [AWS Textractor from CLI](https://aws-samples.github.io/amazon-textract-textractor/commandline.html) which shows the following:

```
textractor start-document-analysis [-h] --features
                               {FORMS,TABLES,QUERIES,SIGNATURES}
                               [{FORMS,TABLES,QUERIES,SIGNATURES} ...]
                               [--queries QUERIES [QUERIES ...]]
                               [--s3-upload-path S3_UPLOAD_PATH]
                               [--s3-output-path S3_OUTPUT_PATH]
                               [--profile-name PROFILE_NAME]
                               [--region-name REGION_NAME]
                               file_source
```

I have done the following which perhaps the single quotes are not needed? trying to ensure I have a full working example to build on. The output continues to show incorrect usage syntax. Tried with and without single quotes and with and without = after flag or name. I get the helper text each time regardless of what I do.

```
textractor start-document-analysis -h --features --queries QUERIES [{"Text":"Who is the Foo", "Alias": "FOO"}] --s3-upload-path 'S3Bucketname' --s3-output-path 'S3BucketName' --region-name 'us-west-2' --file_source '/partition/file.png'
```

Comment: In the [Using Queries — amazon-textract-textractor documentation](https://aws-samples.github.io/amazon-textract-textractor/notebooks/using_queries.html) for Python, it seems to be passing Queries as a _list_. Therefore, perhaps try `--queries ["Who is the Foo?"]`

Answer (score 0):

Reason you're getting helper text every time,
is because you're having argument `-h` right after the command,
which is shorthand for `--help`. Further argument definitions also ought to always be of form `--argument "value"`, or `--argument value`

A correct CLI looks like:

```
textractor start-document-analysis --features QUERIES --queries "Who is the Foo" --s3-upload-path 'S3Bucketname' --s3-output-path 'S3BucketName' --region-name 'us-west-2' --file_source '/partition/file.png'
```

Reference:

- https://aws-samples.github.io/amazon-textract-textractor/commandline.html#available-apis

---

You could also directly invoke Textract API response:

Here's a sample Textract Start Document Analysis sample queries syntax (tested):

```bash
aws textract start-document-analysis \
--document-location '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"test-so-samples","Name":"test-samples/India.pdf"}}' \
--feature-types '["QUERIES"]' \
--queries-config '{"Queries":[{"Text":"What is the official name of India"}]}' \
--output-config '{"S3Bucket":"test-so-samples", "S3Prefix": "samples"}'
--client-request-token 'india-job'
```

Sample response:

```bash
{
    "JobId": "eada2f542f09f4a83dcded92646a74853cdf035b19090b94422e3d501363daac"
}
```